# Updating UILabel value as CAShapeLayer animates

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a circular timer in Swift. I am animating a CAShape layer to fill a ring like below:

[image]

As the bar fills I need to deduct points and update the UILabel in the center. For example if the time limit is 10 seconds and there are 5 points I need to deduct a point every 2 seconds. Initially I was doing this by firing a NSTimer in 2 second time intervals and updating the label accordingly. However I need to be able to restore a previously used circular timer i.e. initalize a timer with 1 second already passed. If I do this firing the timer at 2 second intervals won't work anymore. Is there a way to detect how much of the ring is filled, a callback or something and update the label based on how much of the path is filled and not the time?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a timer trigger at some smaller interval (say each 100ms) and update the UI according to how much time has passed since the timer started. This way the data controls how the UI is displayed and not the other way around (which is a smell in my opinion)

1. Set a repeating timer with small interval
2. trigger your UI updates on each interval